# BigQuery Standard SQL - store query or UDF in table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to store data in a table that can then be converted into either a SQL query or a UDF - like a javascript eval()?

The use case is that I have a list of clients where earnings are calculated in quite significantly different ways for each, and this can change over time. So I would like to have a lookup table which can be updated with a formula for calculating this figure rather than having to write not only hundreds of queries (one for each client) but also maintain these.

I have tried to think if there is a way of having a standard formula that would be flexible enough, but I really don't think it's possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Sure! BigQuery can define and use JS UDFs. The good news is that `eval()` works as expected:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION calculate(x FLOAT64, y FLOAT64, formula STRING)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return eval(formula);
""";

WITH table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 5 as y, 'x+y' formula
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 10, 'x-y'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 15, 'x*y'
)

SELECT x, y, formula, calculate(x, y, formula) result
FROM table;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) That's certainly useful for ad hoc querying. UDFs can't be stored with views, though, right? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That would be a different Stack Overflow question ;)

Comment: Sure :) What I meant more is - it would need to be a JS UDF to achieve this, and therefore that's the question that needs to be asked? There's no way without a UDF by any chance?....

Comment: I don't think we can get to eval() within SQL only